# tabBarController selected index don't work in viewController [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In my iOS app I've a tabBarController with 3 item. When the user taps on the second item, a view is presented (CreateCommentsViewController) and then when user tap on dismiss button I want to change the selected index (from 1 to 0) of tabBarController, but it doesn't work in this way:

```
class CreateCommentViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

func getTabBarController() -> UITabBarController? {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    guard let tabBarController = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController else { return nil }
    return tabBarController
}

@IBAction func dismissNewCommentView(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let tabBarController = getTabBarController()!

    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
    }
}
}
```

And also app delegate code:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window!.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: VIEW_CONTROLLER_IDS.TAB_BAR_CONTROLLER) as! UITabBarController
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Comment: Why a break point?

Comment: yes it's executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try update your action (if you use Swift 5 & 5.1 & 5.2):

```
@IBAction func dismissNewCommentView(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        if let tabBarController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
        }
    }
}
```